# Problema ao imprimir PDF com iText

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports, itext

Tenho que imprimir um relatório Jasper com anexos, que são imagens e outros PDFs. A minha abordagem é passar esse pdf do jasper para o iText e depois, unir com os anexos. Para o método que faz a impressão, eu passo os dados para o relatório e uma lista com o caminho de cada arquivo anexado. Porém quando vou imprimir, se eu imprimir apenas os pdfs, ignorando as imagens, apenas o relatório jasper é imprimido, os outros PDFs não, se eu imprimir o PDF, juntamente com as imagens e os outros PDFs, esse erro é apresentado:

```
Grave: java.io.IOException: file:/home/juliana/docroot/arquivos/livro/2019/5/13/1094-17_(5).pdf is not a recognized imageformat.
at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

**Método de Impressão**

```
public static void imprimirPdfComAnexos(Livro livro, List<ArquivoRelato> arquivosRelato) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException, JRException, BadElementException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    String caminho = "/relatorios/";
    String subPasta = caminho + "livro/";
    String relatorio = subPasta + "livro.jasper";

    List<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<Livro>();
    livros.add(livro);

    InputStream reportStream = context.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(relatorio);

    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    map.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", context.getExternalContext().getRealPath(subPasta) + File.separator);
    map.put("BRASAO_DIR", context.getExternalContext().getRealPath(caminho) + File.separator);

    List<InputStream> listPdfs = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
    List<String> listImagem = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
         HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
          // Resulting pdf

        response.flushBuffer();

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource fonteDados = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(livro);

        //JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, map, fonteDados);

        InputStream reportInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportStream, map, fonteDados)); 

        // Source pdfs
       listPdfs.add(reportInputStream);

        for (ArquivoRelato ar : arquivosRelato) {
            if(ar.getNomeArquivo().substring(ar.getNomeArquivo().lastIndexOf("."), ar.getNomeArquivo().length()).equals("pdf")) {
                listPdfs.add(new FileInputStream(new File(ar.getCaminhoArquivo())));
            }

            else {
                listImagem.add(ar.getCaminhoArquivo());
            }

        }

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(context.getExternalContext().getRealPath("/temp/") + "livroAnexos.pdf"));
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
        document.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
         // Image img = Image.getInstance(bytes)

        for (InputStream in : listPdfs) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                document.newPage();
                //import the page from source pdf
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                //add the page to the destination pdf
                cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        for (String in : listImagem) {
            document.newPage();
            Image image = Image.getInstance(in);
            image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            image.setBorderWidth(0);
            document.add(image);
        }

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=livroAnexos.pdf");

        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

        out.flush();
        document.close();
        out.close();

        File arquivo = new File(context.getExternalContext().getRealPath("/temp/") + "livroAnexos.pdf");
        output.write(org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(new java.io.FileInputStream(arquivo)));
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        document.close();
        servletOutputStream.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema está nessa linha:

```
if(ar.getNomeArquivo().substring(ar.getNomeArquivo().lastIndexOf("."), ar.getNomeArquivo().length()).equals("pdf")) {
```

Seus arquivos de pdf nunca caem nessa condição, e entram na sua lista de imagens, causando o erro. Para corrigir isso, você pode alterar sua comparação para `.pdf` (ao invés de comparar com `pdf`):

```
if(ar.getNomeArquivo().substring(ar.getNomeArquivo().lastIndexOf("."), ar.getNomeArquivo().length()).equals(".pdf")) {
```

Ou até comparar com uma expressão regular:

```
if(ar.getNomeArquivo().matches("^.*\\.pdf$")) {
```

Isso deveria resolver pelo menos esse problema.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, não me atentei que eu precisava comparar a .extensão e não apenas a extensão. Obrigada!

Comment: Que bom que resolveu! Boa sorte por aí!